# NSSplitViewController, Want to disable the behavior of opening sidebar by moving the mouse during full screen

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nssplitviewcontroller

When the screen is set to fullscreen with NSSplitviewController, when the mouse is moved to the left edge, the sidebar opens, or rather, is drawn on top.

I want to disable the above behavior while keeping the opening of the sidebar from the menu enabled.

I did a lot of research and didn't find it.
Is there any way to do this?
Please tellme.

Thanks.

Show Sidebar Menu is OK, Want to avoid coming out by moving to the left edge of the mouse.
[image]

I tried the following, but it didn't work

```swift
    // Neither works.
    self.splitViewItems[0].canCollapse = false

    // It could not be disabled.
    override func splitView(_ splitView: NSSplitView, canCollapseSubview subview: NSView) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    
extension SplitViewController: NSMenuItemValidation {
    // The menu can be disabled if you don't want it to be.
    func validateMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

github:
https://github.com/llscsrl/splitvc

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: Thank you. Added description and code to the text.